# Chrome tab crash on decodeAudioData

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, coffeescript, web-audio-api

Trying to build a webgl audio visualizer with a small engine I made for column landscape which I thought would be great for a frequency distribution over time.

Right now this, which is compiled from coffeescript, crashes the tab:

```
(function() {
  var context, loadSound, onError, playSound, soundBuffer, url;

  context = new webkitAudioContext();

  soundBuffer = void 0;

  url = 'MoxxiTest.ogg';

  loadSound = function(url) {
    var request;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    request.onload = function() {
      context.decodeAudioData(request.response, (function(buffer) {
        soundBuffer = buffer;
        return console.log('hmmm');
      }), onError);
      return console.log('hmmm');
    };
    return request.send();
  };

  playSound = function(buffer) {
    var source;
    source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    return source.noteOn(0);
  };

  onError = function(e) {
    return console.log(e);
  };

  window.onload = function() {
    return loadSound(url);
  };

}).call(this);
```

From testing this is taking place in the decode audio data call of context in the loadSound function.

Tested by using both a mp3 and an ogg of the same file.

Following the tutorials at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/
and http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound
 for info on the web audio api

I'm using XAMPP to get around the cross origin sharing policy if that makes a difference.

Chrome version is: 22.0.1229.94 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that this is something specific to the audio file you are using.  Have you tried using other audio files?  If so I would recommend filing a ticket over at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list.  They are usually pretty good about responding.

Comment: I used another audio file, one from Kevin Macleod's free audio site so it should be fine, same issue with tab crash. Will do for the filing a ticket, thanks.

Comment: I just tested your exact code on Mac OS with an mp3 file of my own http://f.cl.ly/items/3A2N1U02463o0s3p2Z2c/myfirstchiptune.mp3 and it works fine.  Perhaps it is something related to your computer.  I know the Web Audio API has some portability issues running on Windows, Linux, and OS X.

Comment: Figured out the issue. I use a Xonar DG audio card with the channels set at 6 normally. Tried changing it and it works at only 2 channels which I guess is reasonable for a new api. The cue about system specific got me, thanks for the help.